# После кода Pyglet другой код не работает

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7

Нужно было сначала воспроизвести музыку, а потом закрыть. Но после кода с модулем pyglet другой код не как будто не виден.

```
song = pyglet.media.load('C:\\chas.mp3')
song.play()
pyglet.app.run()
break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот тут `pyglet.app.run()` скорее всего создается цикл и он блокирует работу кода после него. Запускайте такой код в отдельном потоке.

Пример:

```
from threading import Thread

def play_song():
    song = pyglet.media.load('C:\\chas.mp3')
    song.play()
    pyglet.app.run()

thread = Thread(target=play_song)
thread.start()

print("Song...")
```

Comment: Можешь, пожалуйста, объяснить. Я просто новичок, пытался на сайтах про это прочитать, но там было не понятно.

Comment: Все равно код выполняется, а дальше пустая строка. Пишу "break", а он игнорируется. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Omicor, `break` прерывает работу внутри циклов, вне циклов он не сработает. Когда вы запускаете скрипт, его код выполняется в главном потоке (в программах минимум один поток работает), а чтобы воспроизводить музыку, `pyglet`нужен цикл обработки событий, запускаемый при `pyglet.app.run()`, этот цикл запускается в том потоке, откуда его вызвали и это не дает выполниться коду после цикла, пока цикл запущен. Поэтому, вариантом может быть запуск `pyglet` в отдельном потоке, чтобы главный поток был свободен и останется возможность что-то в нем выполнять параллельно

Comment: Ну а разве ты не это сделал в ответе?